# LINQ "GroupBy" is adding an empty object

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, linq, ienumerable

I recently encountered a weird behaviour with LINQ and I have a hard time finding the logic behind it.

I declared a list containing 3 structures and then I applied the **.GroupBy** method to that list. The items get grouped but it also adds an empty structure to the list.

Here's an example:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim lstTest As New List(Of structTest)
    lstTest.Add(New structTest With {.intIndex = 1, .strValue = "some value"})
    lstTest.Add(New structTest With {.intIndex = 1, .strValue = "some other value"})
    lstTest.Add(New structTest With {.intIndex = 1, .strValue = "another value"})

    Dim result As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of UInteger, structTest)) = lstTest.GroupBy(Function(x) x.intIndex).ToList()

End Sub

Structure structTest
    Dim intIndex As UInteger
    Dim strValue As String
End Structure
```

If I check the *result* variable using Visual Studio that's what it looks like:

[image]

The .Count property is 3 but there is 4 elements in the list and the last element is an empty element.

My question is: Why is there an additional element ?

Comment: That's just the default capacity of a collection. If you open up `result->Raw View->Non Public Members->Items`, you'll probably see 4 when you have just one containing values. See the Capacity property.

Comment: @Jimi: so why don't you put that into an answer?

Comment: @D.Gaulin as Jimi as pointed out the List grows dynamically by doubling its capacity if `Items.Count` is greater than `Capacity`. On the other hand there is a really weird function called [TrimExcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.trimexcess?view=netcore-3.1) that can remove extra items.